# In Typescript is there a way to constrain an object to be a sub of another object without typing all fields as undefined?

Tags: typescript

More specifically, is there a way to constrain a parameter `someFilters` to be an object which is a sub/partial of another object `filters`, such that `typof someFilters[key] = typeof filters[key]` (But not necessarily the other way around)?

Partial won't do since it defines all of the fields as possibly undefined. Pick requires you to know the keys in advance, while I'm trying to define a general function. I'm looking for either a function generic, or perhaps a type generic that just accepts one type parameter - the type of the big object we are referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a  function that takes in the filter type `T` and an object that is of a type that extends is a `Partial<T>`. This  is expressed as an extra type parameter that extends `Partial<T>`. This means that the actual type of the object passed in will be preserved, so after the object is created there are no extra fields that can be `undefined` on the object:

```
interface Filter {
    searchText: string;
    min: number;
    max: number;
}

function createPartial<T>() {
    return function <P extends Partial<T>>(o: P) {
        return o
    }
}

let subFilter = createPartial<Filter>()({
    min: 1,
})
subFilter.min // ok
subFilter.max // err
```

**Note**: We need to use a function taht returns a function because typescript does not support partial type inference. The function above will work for any `T`, but you could create a version specific to a certain type (ie `Filter`) and remove thus the necessity for this trick. Also [partial type inference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26349) may hit Typescript soon enough.

Comment: Thanks Titian, but with if I just use 
    `function <P extends Partial<IFilter>>(o: P) {
        return o
     }` 
The return will be typed as  all the fields of IFilter possibly undefined.

Comment: @BenCarp yes it will not, that is why I use a function that returns a function. If you don't need such a genera solution (ie just for `Filter` not any `T`) you can use `function <P extends Partial<Filter>>(o: P) { return o }`

Comment: from what I read https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26349 allows you to provide a symbol for a type parameter to be inferred from the actual  parameters which are provided to the function. Though I guess if you combine it with Pick you can get a sub/Partial object (without undefined) as discussed above.

Comment: @BenCarp The refenced issue is still not part of typescirpt, not even typescript@next, so I hesitate to speculate how it would work. My gues would be you could define the function as `function createPartial<T, P extends Partial<T>>(o: P) {
    return o;
}` and call it with `createPartial<Filter, _>({ max : 10 })` but that is mostly speculation based on reading the issue